# Identify Font in this image

Tags: html, css, fonts

Can anyone help me identify the font in this image? I have a client wanting this on their site. I have the script, but not the other.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwSWI.png)

Comment: https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Comment: I tried that as well as font squirrel but didn't get the one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done some research I have found some that might be close to the original, though it is hard to pin point without a crisper image.

What seems clear though is that it is a slab typeface mostly in bold weight and probably display version of it. I hope the ones I link below might be of help to you.

1.
https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/parkinson/modesto/

2.https://www.fontspring.com/fonts/kimmy-design/maxwell-slab

3.https://www.myfonts.com/fonts/blhd/churchward-conserif/